# Building stand-alone static library for Android using Gradle/Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I've transitioned my NDK based app from command-line ant builds to Android Studio.

Android Studio is layered on top of Gradle.
Gradle invokes CMake to build the C++ code.

What I am looking for is a way to build just a set of static .a files for the Android targets armv7, arm64, x86, etc.

Android Studio projects are geared towards complete apps.

Is there a way to have Gradle (or AStudio) build static libs (.a) only, without building an app or shared library?

I'm using all the latest Android stuff under linux:
Android Studio 3.0 canary4.
NDK 15.0.4075724

Comment: if you were using make files w/ Ant, you can still move and use the same make files on AS by tweeking the gradle.NDK properties to employ 'legacy'.   https://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/    "Using android.mk" ....

Answer (score -2):

You can build a static library in Android Studio and Gradle in this 2 ways:

- Adding in your module's Android.mk `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`, using either ndk-build or gradle-experimental plugin.
- Adding in your CMakeLists.txt

  ```
  add_library(mylib STATIC
      source_file1.cpp
      source_file2.
      ... )
  ```

  using Android Studio 2.3+ and adding in your module's build.gradle

  ```
  android{
      defaultConfig{
          externalNativeBuild{
              cmake{
                  \\ add cmake parameters here if you have some
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  and then press Synchronize Gradle Files.
  But always remember that you wouldn't be able to package (add) the builded static library in your app.apk, and hence you wouldn't be able to load the cpp code from the java code. You can only load shared libaries in your android app.

Comment: I know how to build a static lib for my shared lib for my app. I have that working. What I can't manage is create a static lib *without* also building an Android app.

Comment: You can also execute in the gradle view the in ProjectName:NativeModuleName/Tasks/other/externalNativeBuildDebug or  externalNativeBuildRelease and build only your static library